# Vue-cli code splitting creates a file with very long name that can't be served

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3

I'm using vue-cli 3.3.0 and I use code splitting in my router.js file:

```
...
{
      path: "/compliance_checks",
      name: "compChecks",
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      },
      component: () =>
        import("@/shared/policies/compliance/ComplianceChecksPage" /* webpackChunkName: "ComplianceChecksPage" */)
    },
    {
      path: "/firewalls",
      name: "firewalls",
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      },
      component: () =>
        import("@/shared/policies/firewall/ContainerFirewallsPage" /* webpackChunkName: "ContainerFirewallsPage" */)
    },
...
```

Everything works fine in dev mode, when the files are served by the dev server. But after running build I get a 404 error from my server (written in go.

I see it is trying to access a file with a very long name:

> http://localhost:8080/js/AssurancePoliciesPage~ComplianceChecksPage~ContainerFirewallPage~ContainerFirewallsPage~PolicyPage~R~78d0e4db.AssurancePoliciesPage~ComplianceChecksPage~ContainerFirewallPage~ContainerFirewallsPage~PolicyPage~R~78d0e4db.15622d75.js

If I manually shorten the file name (in the dist folder), it manages to load it. So the problem is definitely the length of the file name.

This is my vue.config.js:

```
chainWebpack: config => {
    config.output.chunkFilename(`js/[name].[id].[chunkhash:8].js`);
  },
```

Is it possible to control the generated file name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the config to:

```js
chainWebpack: config => {
    config.output.chunkFilename(`js/[id].[chunkhash:8].js`);
  },
```

That should eliminate the long module name.

If still too long, the `id` (module identifier) is including your long route.  Use [hash] instead of [id].  That will be the hash of the `id` instead of the `id` itself.

```js
chainWebpack: config => {
    config.output.chunkFilename(`js/[hash].[chunkhash:8].js`);
  },
```

Now your filename will reflect the route *and* the contents of the file.

Also the convention is to put the code split comment first.

```js
import( /* webpackChunkName: "ComplianceChecksPage" */ "@/shared/policies/compliance/ComplianceChecksPage")
```

Comment: It helped, thank you, but it still generates a rather long file name, and it will get longer as I add more routes, so still, there is a problem. looks like I'll have to go with only the chunkhash :(

Comment: Does the 'long name' get removed when you eliminate [id]?

Comment: You might want to try: `[hash][chunkhash].js`.  That is the hash of the module id and the hash of the contents.  So if you change a route, but not the contents it will still change.

Comment: i changed to this: `config.output.chunkFilename('js/[chunkhash:8].js');` which works, but the problem is I don't have normal file names

Comment: If you have 2 files with same content there might be an issue... That’s where [hash] is useful